# How to iterate with foreach in divs?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm sorry if question is not clear, let me explain:

I need to achieve the following:

```
<div>
     <div>art 1</div>
     <div>art 2</div>
</div>
<div>
     <div>art 3</div>
     <div>art 4</div>
</div>
<div>
     <div>art 5</div>
     <div>art 6</div>
</div>
etc
```

where each art is inside an array. So far I have tried the following code:

```
foreach $articles as $article{

for($i=1; $i<3; $i++){

    if($i==1){
    echo '<div>';
    }

    echo '<div>'.$article->title.'</div>';


    if($i==2){
    echo '</div>';
    }   
}
```

}

but what i get is not the result i want:

```
<div>
     <div>art 1</div>
     <div>art 1</div>
</div>
<div>
     <div>art 2</div>
     <div>art 2</div>
</div>
<div>
     <div>art 3</div>
     <div>art 3</div>
</div>
etc
```

I don't have a clue how to change value of array every two divs. I haven't found a similar question mainly because I don't know how to search for it. If it is a duplicate please kindly point me to one.

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: You posted wrong code which have syntax error. How can I iterate when it doesn't have $.

Comment: sorry it is a typo, in my real code it has the $

Comment: Your for loop is running twice on every iteration of your foreach. What you might want to do is remove the for loop, and replace it with a simple counter - if the counter is even, add an initial `<div>`; if it's odd, add a trailing `</div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a modulo. A modulo divides by the number and returns the remainder. it's perfect for determining where you are in your count. The character for a modulo is %

```
$counter = 1;
foreach($articles as $article) {
    if($counter % 2 == 1) echo '<div>';
    echo '<div>'.$article->title.'</div>';
    if($counter % 2 == 0) echo '</div>';
    $counter++;
}
if($counter % 2 == 0) echo '</div>';
```

Here's how the math works
First loop, counter is 1. Modulos are only concerned with the **remainder** so it divides whole numbers only. So 1/2 returns 0 with a remainder of 1.
Second loop counter is 2. So 2/2 returns 1 with a remainder of 0.

Here's the same loop with a modulo 3
1 % 3 = 1/3 = 0 remainder 1
2 % 3 = 2/3 = 0 remainder 2
3 % 3 = 3/3 = 1 remainder 0

I hope that helps

Comment: this one worked! Thank you so much! :) Only problem is that if there is an uneven number of articles, the external div remains open. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: It's dividing by 2 ($counter % 2). Just change it to divide by 3 (or however many rows you need) and it will draw at the appropriate times.

Comment: oh I can do an if so that if num_rows returned is uneven it should divide by 3, and if it is even it should divide by 2?

Comment: The code will fail on an odd number of elements, as the last `<div>` will not be closed. [See it here](http://codepad.org/BeglijKT)

Comment: @Machavity could you explain please why when $counter % 2 == 1 it writes the first div? when I start $counter is 1, so 1 % 2 is 0.5 right?

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood what your comment was. I thought you were saying you wanted a row 3 across.
Edited to answer the math question

Comment: wow just saw edited answer! Thanks it worked now :) and also thanks for the math explanation!

Comment: Ok, third time is the charm. I took the time to pop it on my demo server and it worked as written. I forgot to take into account that last $counter++

Answer (score 1):

i dont know codeigniter but in php this should work

```
$i = 0; 
echo "<div>"; 
foreach ( $articles as $article ){  
  echo "<div>" . $article->title . "</div>"; 
  if (++$i % 2 === 0 && $i !== count($articles)) echo "</div><div>";       
} 
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: The code still produces and empty `<div>`-element, when the count is even. [Try it here](http://codepad.org/n3rjBxgz).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach( $articles as $key => $article ){
$key++;
if( $key % 2 == 0  ){
    echo '<div>'.$article->title.'</div>';
    echo '</div><div>';
}else{
    echo '<div>'.$each['title'].'</div>';
}
}
```

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.