# Display SQL data in 3 rows

Tags: php, mysql

I recently adapted a pagination script to work with displaying my mySQL database. It looks fairly nice, but there is one thing I'd like to change up.

Here is how the script looks now: 
http://gyazo.com/7ef0d74caa781ab3e5f72a9935bcd7d0.png

It looks decent, but there is so much extra space on the right. So I figured I'd like to add the same thing on the right, 2 more columns containing more information. In this case, there is only 15, but after doing that there would be 45 results on the page. Now here is the most important part of my script:

```
<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<div id='matchcall' style='float: left'>$row[winner] vs $row[loser] ($row[matches])<br />";

    }
?>
```

Now, please note I have the limit to 15 a page, however, if I do this I can multiply that by 3 and contain more info per page. I thought about ways to solve it, and the only decent one I had was:

```
        if ($row['id'] == 15){
        echo "</div><div style='float: left'>
                    $row[winner] vs $row[loser] ($row[matches])<br />
    }
```

However, this wouldn't work at all because it would only affect the first 15 results, and it wouldn't continue to float the next 15 to the right. So I realized I needed a way to have it recognize a change in 15 and proceed that way. Can anyone shine some light on the subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would use a table to display those results:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Result1</td>
        <td>Result2</td>
        <td>Result3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!--td columns for the results of the second row-->
    </tr>
    <!--And 13 more rows... -->
</table>
```

Note: NEVER use the same id for multiple html tags, that is a VERY bad practice.

```
id='matchcall'
```

is repeated. Use

```
class='matchall'
```

if you need the same value.

And this is how you can generate your table (I am not designing that for you, but you will catch the idea):

```
<?php
    $myTable = "<table>";
    $index = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $modulo = $index % 3;
        if ($modulo === 0) {
            $myTable .= "<tr>";
        } else if ($modulo === 2) {
            $myTable .= "</tr>";
        }
        $myTable .= "<td><div class='matchall'>$row[winner] vs $row[loser] ($row[matches])</div></td>";
        $index++;
    }
    $myTable .= "</table>";
    echo $myTable;
?>
```

Did not have time to test it, but you catch my idea.

Comment: Awesome help, but I really wish I knew more about how modulo worked, as of now I'm just plugging in numbers lol. Anyways, thanks for the help.

Comment: Modulo: Consider the following equation: (a + m) / b = c, where a, b, c and m are integers. We can say that a divided by b equals c, modulo m, because m is the integer number to be added to a so that the result of the sum, divided by b results in an integer. Generally, we choose a value for m which is positive and smaller than b's absolute value (b's distance from the origo). Example: 5 / 2 = 2 mod 1, because 2 * 2 + 1 = 5. Example2: 9 / 7 = 1 mod 2, because 1 * 7 + 2 = 9. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Answer (score 0):

You need a modulo. I have a considerably more in-depth discussion on this thread about how to use them
[How to iterate with foreach in divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186208/how-to-iterate-with-foreach-in-divs/19186321)

Comment: Thanks for the help as well! Your reference was very helpful to my problem.